# How to manage cart details across various devices

Tags: java, design, architecture, problem-solving

Recently I was asked in a interview to implement to e-commerce site .

One of the requirement was to maintain cart details across various devices .(i.e) if user adds a book from his iPhone , and when he again Login from his browser it should be available just like amazon

Should I have to maintain a separate table to maintain cart details per user , and a database call for every event . OR is there any other way of doing it

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head. You will need to store the cart server side, a database works to that end. If speed is an issue there are a number of in memory databases/caches.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is reasonably correct, but I think you're going too granular with the details. You've hit the nail on the head but it takes some effort to filter that nail)hitting part out from other unnecessary additions.

You did mention that you "[were] asked in a interview to implement to e-commerce site", but it's unclear whether you were asked to write code or rather make some quickfire design decisions such as the above example.

I would generally try to match the broad stroke nature of the question. Provided that this is how the question was phrased:

> maintain cart details across various devices

Something as simple as this would've been a complete answer in my opinion:

> Then we need some serverside storage as opposed to local storage.

The nuts and bolts of how you design your API, decide your storage medium, normalize your tables (if any), ... is all just guesswork, since the question does not contain anything to help you decide what the most appropriate choice is.

Part of the skill of a developer is knowing when to abstract and when to dig deep into the nuts and bolts. By digging too deep into a vague question, it could reflect *somewhat* badly on you during an interview if I were the interviewer.
If you're a junior profile, it's not a particular issue and I wouldn't mind. If you're a senior profile, it does raise a valid concern about your ability to self-manage complex tasks that require independent design or analysis.

*If the question was significantly more detailed and you simplified it for the posted question, this answer doesn't apply - or only the general "match the abstraction level of the question" part applies.*

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems to be correct. This is effectively how most systems work. A shopping cart is basically just a table in a database. Think of it as having read/write access from the account. You can log in on any advice and see the items in the cart and also add or delete items.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).